# javascript - PHP Replace Double Quotes

Tags: javascript, php, replace, quotes

I've got this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var EstadoVta= "<?php EstadoDeVentaFn(); ?>";
..........................

</script>
```

That brings the following:

```
var EstadoVta= "<option value="1" >Oculto</option><option value="2" >Activo - Vista</option><option value="3" >Activo - Venta</option><option value="4" >Cancelado</option>";
```

I need to replace the DOUBLE QUOTES.
How can I do it?
Thank You very much!

Comment: Have you tried something to accomplish your goal?

Comment: Of course I did!
But I couldn't reach a solution.
this.EstadoVta.replace(/["']/g, "")
EstadoVta=EstadoVta.replace( """, "'")

Comment: Are you tried any thing? and which double quotes you are talking about?

Comment: @pointup ^ Then include your attempt into your question and show your work/effort!

Comment: I need to replace the DOUBLE QUOTES in <option value="1">, because I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number

Comment: @pointup Well we don't say that in our country